# Serializing a FlatBuffer object to JSON without it's schema file

Tags: c++, json, serialization, flatbuffers

I've been working with FlatBuffers as a solution for various things in my project, one of them specifically being JSON support. However, while FB *natively* supports JSON generation, the documentation for flatbuffers is poor, and the process is somewhat cumbersome. Right now, I am working in the Object->JSON direction. The issue I am having doesn't really arise the other way around (I think).

I currently have JSON generation working per an example I found [here](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/tests/test.cpp) (line 630, `JsonEnumsTest()`) - by parsing a `.fbs` file into a `flattbuffers::Parser`, building and packaging my flatbuffer object, then running `GenerateText()` to generate a JSON string. The code I have is simpler than the example in `test.cpp`, and looks vaguely like this:

```
bool MyFBSchemaWrapper::asJson(std::string& jsonOutput)
{
    //**This is the section I don't like having to do
    std::string schemaFile;
    if (flatbuffers::LoadFile((std::string(getenv("FBS_FILE_PATH")) + "MyFBSchema.fbs").c_str(), false, &schemaFile))
    {
        flatbuffers::Parser parser;
        const char *includePaths[] = { getenv("FBS_FILE_PATH");
        parser.Parse(schemaFile.c_str(), includePaths);
    //**End bad section
        parser.opts.strict_json = true;

        flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder fbBuilder;
        auto testItem1 = fbBuilder.CreateString("test1");
        auto testItem2 = fbBuilder.CreateString("test2");

        MyFBSchemaBuilder myBuilder(fbBuilder);

        myBuilder.add_item1(testItem1);
        myBuilder.add_item2(testItem2);
        FinishMyFBSchemaBuffer(fbBuilder, myBuilder.finish());

        auto result = GenerateText(parser, fbBuilder.GetBufferPointer(), &jsonOutput);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here's my issue: I'd like to avoid having to include the `.fbs` files to set up my `Parser`. I don't want to clutter an already large monolithic program by adding even more random folders, directories, environment variables, etc. I'd like to be able to generate JSON from the compiled FlatBuffer schemas, and not have to search for a file to do so.

Is there a way for me to avoid having to read back in my `.fbs` schemas into the parser? My intuition is pointing to **no**, but the lack of documentation and community support on the topic of FlatBuffers & JSON is telling me there might be a way. I'm hoping that there's a way to use the already generated `MyFBSchema_generated.h` to create a JSON string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see `Mini Reflection` in the documentation: http://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_use_cpp.html

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much. Will `FlatBufferToString()` produce strict JSON like the parser can? The docs you linked said "similar to `Parser`" so I'm wondering what the differences are.

Comment: The two implementations are slightly different, so not sure if they produce exactly the same JSON. But it is easy to modify, if you look at the bottom of https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/include/flatbuffers/minireflect.h you could instantiate your own `ToStringVisitor` and pass `true` for `quoted`.

Comment: Ok, I was able to get everything working after modifying a `ToStringVisitor` to add quotes like you suggested. My code is now much more concise and I'm happy that I won't have to reach out to external files for parsing! The default output of `FlatBufferToString` does seem identical to the default `Parser` configuration while using `GenerateText`, so I did have to instantiate my own visitor. Thanks again for the help; and for making Flatbuffers! I always enjoy getting to interact with prolific software developers on SO :^)